# How to fix signs of variable coefficients apriori in a linear regression model?

Tags: regression, inference, linear-model

I want to restrict the signs of variable coefficients in a linear regression model. For example, if I am using the mtcars dataset from R to build a linear regression model I will get these coefficients:

[image]

In this model, the estimated coefficient for the "disp" variable is positive (0.01334).
But for this "disp" variable, I want to get a negative coefficient instead of a positive one. The coefficients has to be estimated, not fixed superficially. Is there any non-Bayesian methods to do this? Any suggestions on R/Python libraries that can do this are welcomed.